# Check if a date is upcoming or past in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in a table

- event_date ( value is 09/22/2013)
- event_time ( value is 7:11 PM )

Now I want to write a query which should returns row which has time and date in *future* or *past*.

I wrote something  like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM events e
WHERE CONCAT(e.event_date, ' ', e.event_time) <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m/%d/%Y  %g:%i %a')
```

But it didn't work, it's just one of those things which you never know what's wrong with them

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've stored dates in your database as text???

Comment: Store dates/times using the DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data types.

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events
WHERE event_date < CURRENT_DATE()
      OR (event_date = CURRENT_DATE() AND event_time <= CURRENT_TIME())
```

This has the advantage of using any *index* that might exist on `event_date`.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from events e where TIMESTAMP(e.event_date,e.event_time) <= NOW()
```

Comment: CURTIME() returns 08:21:41 :) you can't expect to check a date with it, do you ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution if values of `event_date` and `event_time` are stored as you showed them

Select past events

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(event_date, ' ', event_time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') < NOW()
```

Select future events

```
SELECT *
  FROM events
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(event_date, ' ', event_time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') > NOW()
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f479/2)** demo